# delphi idhttp post related question

Tags: delphi, post, idhttp

im new to delphi. and also almost new to programming world.

i was made some simple post software which using idhttp module.

but when execute it , it not correctly working.

this simple program is check for my account status.

if account login successfully it return some source code which include 'top.location ='

in source, and if login failed it return not included 'top.location ='

inside account.txt is follow first and third account was alived account

but only first account can check, after first account other account can't check

i have no idea what wrong with it

ph896011 pk1089

fsadfasdf dddddss

ph896011 pk1089

following is source of delphi

if any one help me much apprecated!

unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, IdCookieManager, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    lstAcct: TListBox;
    result: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    //procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    //procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    AccList: TStringList;
    IdCookie: TIdCookieManager;
    CookieList: TList;
    StartCnt: Integer;
    InputCnt: Integer;
    WordList: TStringList;
    WordNoList: TStringList;
    WordCntList: TStringList;
    StartTime: TDateTime;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var

  i: Integer;
  //temp: String;
  lsttemp: TStringList;
  sl : tstringlist;
  //userId,userPass: string;
begin
  InputCnt:= 0;
  WordList := TStringList.Create;
  CookieList := TList.create;
  IdCookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(self);


  if FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'account.txt') then
    WordList.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'account.txt');

  WordNoList:= TStringList.Create;
  WordCntList := TStringList.Create;
  lsttemp := TStringList.create;
  sl :=Tstringlist.Create;
try
  try
    for i := 0  to  WordList.Count -1 do
    begin
      ExtractStrings([' '], [' '], pchar(WordList[i]), lsttemp);
      WordNoList.add(lsttemp[0]);
      //ShowMessage(lsttemp[0]);
      WordCntList.add(lsttemp[1]);
      //ShowMessage(lsttemp[1]);

      sl.Add('ID='+ lsttemp[0]);
      sl.add('PWD=' + lsttemp[1]);
      sl.add('SECCHK=0');
      IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      memo1.Text:=idhttp1.Post('http://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/Login/Login.asp',sl);

      if pos('top.location =',Memo1.Text)> 0 then

       begin
        application.ProcessMessages;
       ShowMessage('Alive Acc!');
        //result.Caption := 'alive acc'  ;
        sleep(1000);
        Edit1.Text := 'alive acc';
        lsttemp.Clear;
        Memo1.Text := '';
        //memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('https://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/Login/Logout.asp');
        Sleep(1000);
       end;


      if pos('top.location =', memo1.Text) <> 1 then

      begin
      application.ProcessMessages;
      ShowMessage('bad');
      Edit1.Text := 'bad';
      //edit1.Text := 'bad';
      lsttemp.Clear;
      memo1.Text := '';
      sleep(1000) ;
      end;
      Edit1.Text := '';
    end;

  finally
    lsttemp.free;
  end;
  StartCnt := lstAcct.items.Count;
  StartTime := Now;

finally
  sl.Free;
end;
end;



end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before:

```
sl.Add('ID='+ lsttemp[0]);
```

Do:

```
sl.Clear;
```

On the first run your "SL" holds the two POST parameters, but unless you clear it on the second run, you just keep adding parameters, confusing the HTTP server you're trying to connect to!

That might not be your only problem, but that's surely one of the problems.