# JSON data posted with TIdHTTP.Post not received

Tags: json, delphi, http, delphi-xe2

I can't get my server app to properly receive anything.

Sender code using a design-time TIdHTTP component, with property
Request.Accept = text/html, */*

```
procedure TFrmTTWebserviceTester.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   lJSO : ISuperObject;
   lRequest: TStringStream;
   lResponse: String;
begin
  lJSO := SO('{"name": "Henri Gourvest", "vip": true, "telephones": ["000000000", "111111111111"], "age": 33, "size": 1.83, "adresses": [ { "adress": "blabla", "city": "Metz", "pc": 57000 }, { "adress": "blabla", "city": "Nantes", "pc": 44000 } ]}');
  lRequest := TStringStream.Create(lJSO.AsString,TEncoding.UTF8);   // or ASCII
//  showmessage(lRequest.DataString);  Correct data
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
//  idHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
  lResponse := IdHTTP.Post('http://localhost:8085/ttposttest',lRequest);
//  ShowMessage(lResponse.dataString);
  lRequest.Free;
  lJSO := nil;
end;
```

Receiver is a TWebAction on a TWebModule, set for MethodType mtPost (or mtAny) with handler:

```
procedure TWebModuleWebServices.WebModuleWebServicesTTPostTestAction(
  Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var S: String;
begin
   S := Request.Query;
   Handled := true;
end; { WebModuleWebServicesTTPostTestAction }
```

Request.Query is empty.
All VCL apps. I have read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871590/delphi-idhttp-post-related-question) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176926/delphi-7-how-to-send-a-post-idhttp-request-in-a-console-application) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924525/idhttp-post-error) and many others but must be overlooking something...

TIA, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TWebRequest.Query` property returns the URL query string, which you are not sending any.  That is why it is blank.  Your `POST` data is accessible from the `TWebRequest.Content` and `TWebRequest.RawContent` properties instead.